# Under what conditions are std::forward<X> and static_cast<X&&> equivalent?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0644r1.html says

> There are two ways that you can forward a variable: you can use std::forward or you can use static_cast directly (as this proposal's forwarding operator does):
>
> ```
>    template <class X, class Y>
>    decltype(auto) foo(X&& x, Y&& y) {
>        return std::forward<X>(x)(std::forward<Y>(y));    // with std::forward
>        return static_cast<X&&>(x)(static_cast<Y&&>(y));  // with static_cast, exactly equivalent
>    }
> ```

Does the "exactly equivalent" apply because `X` and `Y` are template parameters and so `X&&` and `Y&&` are forwarding references? Or for some other reason?

I assume it doesn't always apply because if it did

1. I would expect `std::forward`'s documentation to say so, [as `std::move`'s does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move);
2. There would be no reason for the 14% compilation speedup from replacing one with another.

My current best guess is that:

1. `std::forward` doesn't compile in some cases `static_cast` does;
2. But not vice versa: if `std::forward` compiles, so does `static_cast`;
3. If it compiles, both have the same result.

But I am far from confident it is correct.

Comment: Your guess 2 and 3 are wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/nE6xad3hq

Comment: @DrewDormann No, I wasn't. I understand they are equivalent on forwarding references (though on rereading, I didn't make that clear enough), and was asking if they are equivalent in other cases as well.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Those "other cases" are complicated, because then we not only have to consider various types `X` but also the type of the argument/operand.  Is there some relationship between them other than the one in the example that you want considered, or are you really asking about all possibilities whatsoever?

Comment: @DavisHerring I am interested in the general case, but any particular differences (like in Artyer's example) would also be good.

Answer (score 0):

To be truly general, we have to look to the definitions of `static_cast<X&&>(…)` and `std::forward<X>(…)`.  Note that we may ignore the case where `X` is not a reference type, since via reference collapsing it ends up equivalent to the corresponding rvalue reference type.  So let `X` be `Y&` or `Z&&`, where `Y` and `Z` are not reference types.

In the lvalue-reference case, the relevant `static_cast` capabilities are (where `B` is `Y` or a base class of it)

1. `B&` → `Y&`
2. `Y &x(…);`

and the instantiated declarations for `std::forward` are

```
constexpr Y& forward(Y&) noexcept;
constexpr Y& forward(Y&&) noexcept;  // definition ill-formed
```

In the rvalue-reference case, they are (where additionally `D` is `Z` or a class derived from it)

1. `B&&` → `Z&&`
2. `D&` → `Z&&`
3. `Z &&x(…);`

and

```
constexpr Z&& forward(Z&) noexcept;
constexpr Z&& forward(Z&&) noexcept;
```

The reference parameters to `std::forward` are copy-initialized from the argument, whereas `static_cast` can do one of three things:

1. direct-initialization from its operand, which causes overload resolution differences when **explicit** conversion functions are involved (as noted by Artyer),
2. **downcast**, so that `static_cast<Derived&&>(Base())` works while `std::forward<Derived>(Base())` cannot implicitly convert the argument, or
3. the implementation of `std::forward` itself, which (as one would hope!) doesn't contribute any distinction since it applies only to the rvalue case, where one of the two overloads of `std::forward` will equivalently accept any derived type.